# Defining sub complexes of simplicial homology groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to formally define the subcomplexes that generate some simplicial homology group. Are the generators of a homology group this subcomplex or are they just a set of representative simplices?

For example I have some disconnected simplicial complex and I would like to obtain the subcomplexes that are disjoint. How would the set of these complexes be defined?

Comment: I don't know of a way of finding canonical generators for your homology groups in general in any natural way. Can you state your question more clearly please? Maybe I'm misunderstanding you

Comment: Sorry. I suppose I am asking what class of objects do the generators of a homology group belong to? Suppose I have a simplicial complex that is just two disconnected sub-complexes. Can I use the homology groups to determine exactly what those sub-complexes look like (i.e. what d-simplices are in it)? Or does simplicial homology just tell me there are two components?

Comment: Taking homology of the disjoint union of two simplicial complexes just amounts to taking the homology of the individual complexes and then adding them. This is known as the "additive" property of homology. Stated clearly: $H_i(X \sqcup Y) = H_i(X) \oplus H_i(Y)$ where $\sqcup$ is what's called the "coproduct" of simplicial complexes.